# How to stub/mock submodules of a require of nodejs using sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am using sinon as for unit testing a nodejs(Hapijs) functionality. This function is in index.js. I am include the index.js in my test file as

```
    var index=require('./index.js');
```

But again inside the index.js there is require

```
    var library= require('./library.js')
```

Again the library.js has the require of a third part functionality

```
     var googlelib=require('googlelib')
```

Now when I run my testfile testfunc.js below

```
    var index= require('./index.js');
    var assert = require('assert');
    var sinon = require('sinon');
    var proxyquire= require('proxyquire');
```

I get the below error

```
    Error: Cannot find module './library'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

I would like to know if there is any way I can stub the inner require library.js of index.js (as there are many requires inside index.js and many requires of requires)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stub a requried modules by using [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire), using it like this.

```js
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

const stubs = {
    './library': (some, argument) => {
        assert.equal(some, 'thing');
        return 'Some ' + argument;
    },
};

const index = proxyquire('./index', stubs);

index();
```

This will run the function `stubs['./library']` whenever  `./library` is called in `index.js`.

If `library.js` exports an object with functions, just make `stubs` reflect that, and make sure to call them what they are called in `index.js` and `library.js`.

```js
const stubs = {
    './library': {
        more: (argument) => {},
        methods: (argument) => {},
    },
};
```

Read the docs for more information. Use this in conjunction with a test framework like [Mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha) or [Jasmine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine).

Also, the error you get does not seem to come from your test file, but rather your index file. This answers your question, but you might want to look into what is causing your error, or rather, why `index.js` can't find `library.js`. Make sure they are in the same folder.

Comment: I am stucked with reading the const file which is called inside library.js. I am thinking of doing through the proxyquire stubbs but still I get the same config not found error.