# Unable to read config.json file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am writing a unit test case for the , question is mentioned in the link [How to stub/mock submodules of a require of nodejs using sinon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115128/how-to-stub-mock-submodules-of-a-require-of-nodejs-using-sinon)

when I include a require

```
 const index=require('./index.js');
```

It has a library require inside it

```
 const library= require('./library.js');
```

the library.js file has a require which reads config.json file(this config file is also required inside above index.js) as below

```
 const readConfig = require('read-config');
 const config = readConfig('./config.json');
```

I have tried many ways as suggested in the above link but I am failing

```
  const stubs = {
'./library': function (response) {
    assert.equal(some, null);
    return 'Some ' + argument;
 },
   '../library1.js': {
    function(paths, opts){
      var config='./config.json'
      return config;
    }
  },
}

 const index=proxyquire('./index.js',stubs)
```

When I run my unit test case I am still getting the below error

```
      throw configNotFound(configPath);
        ^
ReadConfigError: Config file not found: ./config.json
```

I would like to know which part of the code I am missing badly that the code throws the error

I am trying to edit the index.js and all the related files where config is read with the below code

```
var path = require('path');
var pathToJson = path.resolve(__dirname, '../config.json');

 // Load config
 var config = fs.readFile(pathToJson , 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  config = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Here challenge is that I cannot change the node code

Answer (score 0):

You problem is likely to be path resolution. If `./config.json` is relative to where you are running Node from (`process.cwd()`), then it'll work. If it's relative to your library module, then you can do something like:

```
// Works for JS and JSON
const configPath = require.resolve('./config.json');

// Works in general
const configPath = require('path').join(__dirname, 'config.json');

// Then
const readConfig = require('read-config');
const config = readConfig(configPath);
```

It's difficult to say if this is the case without knowing more about your project layout and how you're starting your app.

Comment: The nodejs(in hapijs) code(which has config.json) is already there and it is working. I am trying to write unit testcases for the various APIs inside the index.js file as i given in the question. But here comes the error and I must not change the configPath or add a new code to the hapi.js apis

Comment: Is ther anyway I can mock the module from where this config.json is read. Actually as given in the question the config.json is read from library.js and instead of changing the code, can I mock the config.json

Comment: It's possible to mock entire modules using https://www.npmjs.com/package/sandboxed-module or https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire. It makes testing more awkward, but your options are limited when modules are doing stuff before you have a chance to modify the exports of their submodules (or files they load etc.)