# Sinon doesn't stub my intern fuctions while testing. (ExpressJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, sinon

currently I want to implement sinon stub's for my express routes. The problem is, that I don't understand why it isnt replacing my functions.

My test should make a request to my login-route and instead of calling the authenticate function, my login-route should call the fake function. Any Idea how to do it?

My project-structure

```
/src/http/routes/login.js
/src/http/middlewares/user-midd.js
/test/test.js
```

**test.js:**

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);

const rawapp = require('../src/http/app');

let stub;

try {
    stub = sinon.stub(require('../src/http/middlewares/user-midd').create(),'authenticate')

    proxyquire('../src/http/middlewares/user-midd', {
        'authenticate': stub
    });

    stub.callsFake((request, response, next) => {
        console.log("IM IN FAKE CALL FUNCTION", request, response, next)
        return next()
    })

    chai.request(rawapp())
        .get('/api/v1/de/login')
        .set('X-Xamarin-Client-Version', 1)
        .then((res) => {
            expect(res).to.have.status(200)
            done();
        }).catch(err => console.error(err))
} catch (err) { console.error(err) }
```

**login.js:**

```
function loginRoute() {
  const authenticate = userMiddleware.create().authenticate;
  const login = new express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

  login.get('/', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    logger.info(new Date(), 'In login route GET /');
    console.log("LOGIN FUNCTION")
    res.status(res.locals.statusCode).json(res.locals.user);
  });

  return login;
}

module.exports.create = loginRoute;
```

and the lastly my **route-middleware:** (user-midd.js)

```
    module.exports.create = function create() {
  function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    console.log("AUTHENTIFICATION FUNCTION")
    const authHeader = req.get('authorization');
    const userAuthHeader = req.get('user-authorization') || '';

    if (authHeader) {
      const mandator = req.params.mandator;
      const path = `api/v1/${mandator}/login`;

      logger.info(hostname + path);
      return request
      .get(hostname + path)
      .set('Authorization', authHeader)
      .set('User-Authorization', userAuthHeader)
      .then((mbaasRes) => {
        logger.info('Got response from service - status : ', mbaasRes.statusCode);

        res.locals.user = {};
        res.locals.statusCode = mbaasRes.statusCode;

        if (mbaasRes.body) {
          res.locals.user = mbaasRes.body;
        }

        setUserAuthHeader.setHeader(mbaasRes, res);

        return next();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        logger.error('service user call failed - err : ', err);
        return next(err);
      });
    }

    const error = {
      msg: 'Unauthorized',
      statusCode: 401,
    };

    return next(error);
  }

  return {
    authenticate,
  };
};
```

The result of executing my test is: 
**expected { Object (_events, _eventsCount, ...) } to have status code 200 but got 500'**

Means that while testing, it doesn't replace the "authenticate" function.
What Im doing wrong?

Comment: And welcome to SO. Remember to mark answers as accepted, if it helped you.

Comment: in your test file, I saw a method name "authenticate". May I know where it is in your source file?

Comment: I've updated it, sorry it was a mistake. Now its clearer I hope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**proxyquire** may not required here, we can just use **Sinon**.

This may works

```
...

describe('app test', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    sinon.stub(userMiddleware, 'create').returns({ // use returns of Sinon
      authenticate: sinon.stub.callsFake((request, response, next) => {
        console.log("IM IN FAKE CALL FUNCTION", request, response, next); 
        next();
      })
    });
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    sinon.restore()
  });

  it('success', function(done) {
    chai.request(rawapp())
      .get('/api/v1/de/login')
      .set('X-Xamarin-Client-Version', 1)
      .then((res) => {
          expect(res).to.have.status(200)
          done();
      }).catch(err => console.error(err))
  });
})
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Thats working fine! Can you maybe also give me a idea how to do it without the create function? I mean when userMiddleware returns the authenticate method?

Comment: glad it helped. Are you saying that you want to avoid calling `create()` function to get `authenticate` function?

Comment: Yep. That would be awesome. I mean when the user-middleware exports directly the authenticate function: module.exports = authenticate function...

Comment: yes that is possible, we can achieve something like `module.exports = function(req, res, next) { // implementation }`, for this case, the testing become more challenging, we may need to use `proxyquire`

Comment: If you  would know how to do it, it would be awesome. We can also do it together via chat if you want :)

Comment: @A.Sinan sure, just ping me in the chat :)

Comment: How can I ping you in which chat? :D

Comment: I'm also not sure, perhaps through https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users

Answer (score 2):

That is not how Sinon works. If you want to mock functions required in from other files, you should take a look at [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire).

See one of my [earlier answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115128/how-to-stub-mock-submodules-of-a-require-of-nodejs-using-sinon/48115900#48115900) for an explanation.

Comment: First of all, thanks for replying.
But I still have the problem and maybe you can explain me what Im doing wrong:
Can you please again look at my updates testcode? 
THANKS